# Minimum norm polynomial subject to equality constraints

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Given distinct points $x_1,\dots,x_m \in [0,1]^n$ and real numbers $y_1,\dots,y_m$ with $m > 1$, let $\mathbb{P} = \{p \text{ is a real polynomial on } \mathbb{R}^n :p(x_1) = y_1, \dots, p(x_m) = y_m\}.$

Let $\|p\| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]^n} |p(x)|.$

What is the value of $M = \inf\{\|p\| \colon p \in \mathbb{P}\}$?

Clearly we must have $M \geq \max \{ |y_1| , \dots, |y_m| \}$. Does the equality hold?